# I called an unbounded function in class with the class name but i got that error?

Tags: python-2.7, class

```
class DemoClass:
    def add_function(a, b):
        return a + b
DemoClass.add_function(5, 60)
```

Output:
TypeError: unbound method add_function() must be called with DemoClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize a `DemoClass` object to call the method e.g.

```
class DemoClass:
    def add_function(a, b):
         return a + b

demo = DemoClass()
demo.add_function(5, 60)
```

Alternatively, you can make `add_function` a static method that can be accessed via the class name e.g.

```
class DemoClass:
    @staticmethod
    def add_function(a, b):
        return a + b

DemoClass.add_function(5, 60)
```